# How can I sort my xml file by a subelement, using lxml module in python?

Tags: python, xml, sorting, lxml

I'm use python 2.
I use for handle the xml file the lxml module.
I need sort my xml file by tag 'DATE'.

For example the file in input is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ARCHIVE>
  <TCASE>
    <NAME>DISC</NAME>
    <DATE>04/30/2021 16:14:55</DATE>
    <VERDICT>PASS</VERDICT>
    <LOG>DISC_2021_04_30_16_14_55\DISC_2021_04_30_16_14_55.xml</LOG>
  </TCASE>
  <TCASE>
    <NAME>SEC</NAME>
    <DATE>04/30/2021 16:23:19</DATE>
    <VERDICT>INCONC</VERDICT>
    <LOG>SEC_2021_04_30_16_23_19\SEC_2021_04_30_16_23_19.xml</LOG>
  </TCASE>
  <TCASE>
    <NAME>SEC</NAME>
    <DATE>04/30/2021 16:17:01</DATE>
    <VERDICT>INCONC</VERDICT>
    <LOG>SEC_2021_04_30_16_17_01\EC_2021_04_30_16_17_01.xml</LOG>
  </TCASE>
</ARCHIVE>
```

After the handling the file becomes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ARCHIVE>
      <TCASE>
        <NAME>DISC</NAME>
        <DATE>04/30/2021 16:14:55</DATE>
        <VERDICT>PASS</VERDICT>
        <LOG>DISC_2021_04_30_16_14_55\DISC_2021_04_30_16_14_55.xml</LOG>
      </TCASE>
      <TCASE>
        <NAME>SEC</NAME>
        <DATE>04/30/2021 16:17:01</DATE>
        <VERDICT>INCONC</VERDICT>
        <LOG>SEC_2021_04_30_16_17_01\EC_2021_04_30_16_17_01.xml</LOG>
      </TCASE>
      <TCASE>
        <NAME>SEC</NAME>
        <DATE>04/30/2021 16:23:19</DATE>
        <VERDICT>INCONC</VERDICT>
        <LOG>SEC_2021_04_30_16_23_19\SEC_2021_04_30_16_23_19.xml</LOG>
      </TCASE>
    </ARCHIVE>
```

Thanks for your help.

I tried with this code. But it does not work well.

```
def getkey(self, elem):
    return datetime.strptime(elem.get('DATE'), "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")

def produce_tc_log_XML(self, pathlayer):
        fileName = os.path.join(pathlayer, "tc_log.xml")
        if os.path.isfile(fileName):
            # print("File exist")
            tree = ET.parse(fileName)
            archive = tree.getroot()
            tcase = archive.find('TCASE')
            tcase[:] = sorted(tcase, key=self.getkey)
        else:
            # print("File not exist")
            archive = ET.Element("ARCHIVE")

        ET.indent(archive, space = "  ")
        xmlstr = ET.tostring(archive, xml_declaration = True, encoding = utf-8", pretty_print = True)
        with open(fileName, "w") as f:
            f.write(xmlstr)
            f.close()
```

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: you can use `lxml` to get all `TCASE`, next you can use `for`-loop to get `DATE` from every `TCASE` and create list of pairs `(text from DATE, TCASE)` and next you can use `sorted()` on this list. Next you have to use `for`-loop to  put all `TCASE` back in `ARCHIVE`

Comment: what meas `it does not work` ? Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it should be `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` - `month` before `day` and upper `Y` for 4-digits year. In `04/30/2021` you can't have `month = 30`

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` with `month/day/YEAR` - you can't have `month = 30`.
You have to use upper case `Y` to get 4-digits year.

I had to run it without `.find('TCASE')` and with `.find('DATE').text` instead of `.get('DATE')`

---

My code. I used module `io` only to simulate file.

```py
text ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ARCHIVE>
  <TCASE>
    <NAME>DISC</NAME>
    <DATE>04/30/2021 16:14:55</DATE>
    <VERDICT>PASS</VERDICT>
    <LOG>DISC_2021_04_30_16_14_55\DISC_2021_04_30_16_14_55.xml</LOG>
  </TCASE>
  <TCASE>
    <NAME>SEC</NAME>
    <DATE>04/30/2021 16:23:19</DATE>
    <VERDICT>INCONC</VERDICT>
    <LOG>SEC_2021_04_30_16_23_19\SEC_2021_04_30_16_23_19.xml</LOG>
  </TCASE>
  <TCASE>
    <NAME>SEC</NAME>
    <DATE>04/30/2021 16:17:01</DATE>
    <VERDICT>INCONC</VERDICT>
    <LOG>SEC_2021_04_30_16_17_01\EC_2021_04_30_16_17_01.xml</LOG>
  </TCASE>
</ARCHIVE>'''

#from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree as ET
from datetime import datetime
import io

tree = ET.parse(io.BytesIO(text.encode()))  # Python 2 lxml, xml, Python 3

archive = tree.getroot()

def get_date(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x.find('DATE').text, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

archive[:] = sorted(archive, key=get_date)

print(ET.tostring(archive).decode())
```

Comment: Good, now it works correctly. Thanks a lot.